# How to run this function on an interval?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to run everything within the `checkUser()` function but its not running on the interval specified. Maybe there is a better way to do this? I am just trying to check the address every few minutes. The line `const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });` does get the address and works fine if I just run it once. Just need to try do it on an interval though. Full code below:

```
function checkUser()
            {
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
                //we use eth_accounts because it returns a list of addresses owned by us.
                const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
                //We take the first address in the array of addresses and display it
                // getAccountsResult.innerHTML = accounts[0] || 'not able to get accounts';

                 console.log(accounts); //test one

                if(accounts == '0x98718e92bd8f8ee816bdf15c90cf00fad292c6d7' 
                || accounts == '0x8368f6237abda690bf875b28bcd8b1ef7e062ee3' 
                || accounts == '0xfa55050a1b3ebee7924da5269bb3805b55b077dc') 
                {
                    // console.log("you are going in!");
                    // window.location.href = "members_home.html";
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(accounts); //test one
                    window.location.href = "normal_home.html";
                }
             });

            }
            setInterval(checkUser, 50);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function adds an eventListener on DOMContentLoaded. So when you run this function at an interval you create a new eventlistener every 50ms. If you want to run the function inside eventListener at the specified interval you can put it in a seperate function.

```js
async function checkUser() {
  // we use eth_accounts because it returns a list of addresses owned by us.
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
  // We take the first address in the array of addresses and display it
  // getAccountsResult.innerHTML = accounts[0] || 'not able to get accounts';

  console.log(accounts); //test one

  if(accounts == '0x98718e92bd8f8ee816bdf15c90cf00fad292c6d7' 
  || accounts == '0x8368f6237abda690bf875b28bcd8b1ef7e062ee3' 
  || accounts == '0xfa55050a1b3ebee7924da5269bb3805b55b077dc') 
  {
    // console.log("you are going in!");
    // window.location.href = "members_home.html";
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(accounts); //test one
    window.location.href = "normal_home.html";
  }

}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkUser);
setInterval(checkUser, 50);
```

This way the function gets executed when the dom content is loaded and every 50ms.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer so others know this answer resolves the issue

Comment: @CasperKuethe please approve my edit fixing code formatting and brackets.

Comment: @DadiBit I’ve tried but I can’t see the edit, it’s bugging out. EDIT: nvm thanks for your edit!

Answer (score 0):

Why are `DOMContentLoaded` and `setInterval` inside your `checkUser` function ?

Your instructions order is all wrong.

Reading your code, I think you don't even want to use setInterval...

I guess what you want to do is :

1. wait for `DOMContentLoaded` to define `checkUser`
2. `checkUser` to do the `ethereum.request`

   ```
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {

       // define checkUser
       function checkUser() {
           const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
           //We take the first address in the array of addresses and display it
           // getAccountsResult.innerHTML = accounts[0] || 'not able to get accounts';

           console.log(accounts); //test one

           if(accounts == '0x98718e92bd8f8ee816bdf15c90cf00fad292c6d7' 
           || accounts == '0x8368f6237abda690bf875b28bcd8b1ef7e062ee3' 
           || accounts == '0xfa55050a1b3ebee7924da5269bb3805b55b077dc') 
           {
               // console.log("you are going in!");
               // window.location.href = "members_home.html";
           }
           else
           {
               console.log(accounts); //test one
               window.location.href = "normal_home.html";
           }
       }

       // run checkUser
       checkUser();
   }
   ```